# How to get a timestamp in node js without colons

Tags: node.js, date, timestamp

Here's what i'm doing right now

```
var date = new Date();
var timestamp = date.toUTCString();  
var timestampu = timestamp+".png"; 
console.log(timestampu);
```

The result that I am trying to get is "(day) (month) (date) (time).png" like this 
"Sunday August 8/25/29 12-10-00.png"

The problem I have is that you cant save a file with a colon ":" in it, So what I have is useless :(

Help!

Comment: Did my answer work for what you intended?

Comment: Yes thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) all dashes with a character that can be saved, such as a dot or space.

```
var timestampu = timestamp.replace("-", ".") + ".png";
```